# Get .exe from my nuget package in another project

Tags: c#, .net

so I have created a nuget package from a project RtecController in which there is everything detailed in the .nuspec :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>RtecController</id>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <title>RtecController</title>
        <authors>TB</authors>
        <description>RtecController Package</description>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Add dependencies here -->
        </dependencies>
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/RtecController.exe" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
            <files include="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/PlatformXYZ.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="true" />
            <files include="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/MechStressCore.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="true" />
            <files include="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="true" />
            <files include="../dll/gclibo.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="true" />
            <files include="../dll/gclib.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="true" />
        </contentFiles>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <!-- Include files here -->
        <file src="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/RtecController.exe" target="content/RtecController.exe" />
        <file src="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/PlatformXYZ.dll" target="content/PlatformXYZ.dll" />
        <file src="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/MechStressCore.dll" target="content/MechStressCore.dll" />
        <file src="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf.dll" target="content/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf.dll" />
        <file src="../dll/gclibo.dll" target="content/gclibo.dll" />
        <file src="../dll/gclib.dll" target="content/gclib.dll" />
        <file src="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/RtecController.exe" target="contentFiles/RtecController.exe" />
        <file src="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/PlatformXYZ.dll" target="contentFiles/PlatformXYZ.dll" />
        <file src="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/MechStressCore.dll" target="contentFiles/MechStressCore.dll" />
        <file src="bin/Release/net6.0-windows/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf.dll" target="contentFiles/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf.dll" />
        <file src="../dll/gclibo.dll" target="contentFiles/gclibo.dll" />
        <file src="../dll/gclib.dll" target="contentFiles/gclib.dll" />
    </files>
</package>
```

I need the RtecController.exe from the package in order to make my project MFT working. This is what the MFT.csproj looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{C9DA6176-0C77-4554-8A3F-8B3154CCDC72}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MFT</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MFT</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>
    </TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <MyType>Custom</MyType>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <IncrementalBuild>true</IncrementalBuild>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>MFT.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036,42314</NoWarn>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <IncrementalBuild>false</IncrementalBuild>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>MFT.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036,42314</NoWarn>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionExplicit>On</OptionExplicit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionCompare>Binary</OptionCompare>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionStrict>Off</OptionStrict>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OptionInfer>On</OptionInfer>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>MFT.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036,42314</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <CodeAnalysisLogFile>bin\Debug\MFT.exe.CodeAnalysisLog.xml</CodeAnalysisLogFile>
    <CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>true</CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>
    <CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>GlobalSuppressions.vb</CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets</CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\\Rules</CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>MFT.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036,42314</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <CodeAnalysisLogFile>bin\Release\MFT.exe.CodeAnalysisLog.xml</CodeAnalysisLogFile>
    <CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>true</CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>
    <CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>GlobalSuppressions.vb</CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets</CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\\Rules</CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>
    <CodeAnalysisFailOnMissingRules>false</CodeAnalysisFailOnMissingRules>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>rtecmft.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>MFT.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036,42314</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>MFT.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036,42314</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="RtecController" Version="24.2.22" />
    <Reference Include="Accessibility">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ControlzEx, Version=3.0.2.4, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ControlzEx.3.0.2.4\lib\net45\ControlzEx.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MahApps.Metro, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MahApps.Metro.1.6.2\lib\net46\MahApps.Metro.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ControlzEx.3.0.2.4\lib\net45\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsFormsIntegration" />
    <Reference Include="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit">
      <HintPath>..\dll\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="Application.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Compile Include="ComponentConfig.xaml.vb">
      <DependentUpon>ComponentConfig.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="DataConfig.xaml.vb">
      <DependentUpon>DataConfig.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SystemConfigure.xaml.vb">
      <DependentUpon>SystemConfigure.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UCNotification.xaml.vb">
      <DependentUpon>UCNotification.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Page Include="ComponentConfig.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="DataConfig.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="Application.xaml.vb">
      <DependentUpon>Application.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.vb">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Page Include="SystemConfigure.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Themes\Rtec2.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="UCNotification.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="System.Linq" />
    <Import Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Import Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <Import Include="System" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Import Include="System.Diagnostics" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Controls" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Documents" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Input" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Shapes" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Media" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Media.Imaging" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Navigation" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="ModuleMain.vb" />
    <Compile Include="My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My Project\MyExtensions\MyWpfExtension.vb">
      <VBMyExtensionTemplateID>Microsoft.VisualBasic.WPF.MyExtension</VBMyExtensionTemplateID>
      <VBMyExtensionTemplateVersion>1.0.0.0</VBMyExtensionTemplateVersion>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My Project\Resources.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My Project\Settings.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="My Project\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
      <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="My Project\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <AppDesigner Include="My Project\" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\Addin.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\Info.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\process_help.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\RtecN2.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\play.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\stop.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\play1.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\play2.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\play-64.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\stop-64.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\ffae2d-play-64.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\ffae2d-stop-64.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="RtecN.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\Products.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\RtecBkG1.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\RtecBkG.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\RtecBkG2.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\RtecBkG3.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Service References\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MechStressCore\MechStressCore.vbproj">
      <Project>{64626DA7-F7FB-443E-ACF5-002400DA5BC9}</Project>
      <Name>MechStressCore</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MFTCore\MFTCore.csproj">
      <Project>{396edd89-7996-4d25-b292-26a73e3342b1}</Project>
      <Name>MFTCore</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TribologyApp\TribologyApp.vbproj">
      <Project>{53202304-9F6C-4E38-B90F-9A319D02A200}</Project>
      <Name>TribologyApp</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\RtecN4.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.4.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Windows Installer 4.5</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\notif.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\notif2.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\RtecMft.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="rtecmft.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\Home_Button.png" />
    <Resource Include="Images\SS_Home_Button.jpg" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>copy /Y $(SolutionDir)TribologyApp\$(OutDir)*  $(TargetDir)</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

How can i get the RtecController.exe from the nuget package into the output directory of the MFT project ?

Thanks in advance.

I've tried a lot of things of none of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `CopyToOutputDirectory`. You should specify it in your .csproj-file. For example something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="content\RtecController.exe">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Make sure the relative path to RtecController.exe is correct based on the location of your NuGet package and your MFT project. The CopyToOutputDirectory attribute ensures that the file will be copied to the output directory during build.
After making these modifications, build your MFT project. The RtecController.exe file should now be copied to the output directory of the MFT project during the build process.

Keep in mind that paths and configurations might slightly differ based on your project structure and the way the NuGet package is set up, **so you might need to adjust these paths accordingly.**